C# Model Animation, Model display is distorted during Animation
I have ported a CPP Model Animation program to C# using Opentk and Assimp. The model displays correctly, texture etc... when I apply the animation, th emodel seems to animate correctly, but the model is totlaly distorted.
I have printed and compared almost everything between the CPP program and the C# program. Vertices, bones, weights, interpolations, shaders, etc. All data matches except the interpolations because of timing differences. The calculations are the same. A single Mesh DAE file.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others to provide an answer faster.
